# Pymongo find(): Having issues filtering data

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to filter out data from a collection based on a particular id, but looks like they are not really filtered out.

My code looks something like this:

```
myid = '100'
for x in collection.find({},{"myid": myid}):
    print(x)
```

I am not sure if I am going wrong with the syntax somewhere, can someone please help.

Comment: The filter is specified as the first argument of `find` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way out

```
myid = '100'
for x in list(collection.find({"myid": myid})):
    print(x)
```

Since only collection.find() will return you a pymongo object. So, in order to make that object iterable you have to convert it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

The first two parameters to `.find()` are a `filter` and a `projection`; you have passed your filter to the projection parameter. You just need this:

```
myid = '100'
for x in collection.find({"myid": myid}):
    print(x)
```

There is no need to convert it explicitly to a list as `.find()` returns an iterable object already.